# Mutable List in Kotlin not getting updated

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, mutablelist

here, I am getting current user data using snapshot. user is a data class that contains several variables and a mutable list of strings. here I am taking input from users and making a new mutable list of strings and first putting data from the current users mutable list and then putting input by the user and then updating this mutable list at the place of the current user mutable list.
Problem: mutable list shows only one string(recently added one) and all the previous strings are not stored

```
val todoTitle = edToEditTitle.text.toString()       //getting data from user    
var mutableList = mutableListOf<String>()  //making a new mutable list
if(todoTitle.isNotEmpty()){            //if data entered by user is not empty
    auth.currentUser?.let {              
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("users")
            .document(it.uid)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val product: user? = task.result.toObject(user::class.java)       //getting the current data snapshot for current user(which contains a mutable list of strings)
                    Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "onComplete: $product")
                    if (product != null) {
                            for(i in product.list!!){    //if current users mutable list is not empty
                                mutableList.add(i);  //add contents to new mutable list
                            }
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "onComplete: ", task.exception)
                }
            }
    }
    mutableList.add(todoTitle);    //add new input also
    db.collection("users").document(auth.currentUser!!.uid).update("list",mutableList)    //update current users list
```

Comment: Maybe the task returns an unsuccessful response or the product task result cannot convert successfully to the user object. Therefore product list is null and the product list is empty.

Comment: I think that this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help.